# Order of loading custom MediaWiki CSS skin

Tags: css, mediawiki

I am using a MediaWiki wiki with [custom skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning). Now I see the CSS code of my custom skin overridden by the CSS code of MediaWiki itself.

[image]

How can I change the order of loading CSS code?

Comment: Can you add "?debug=true" to the URL? That will help you to see where exactly those lines are being read from. Also, it's interesting to note that "!important" was added to the CSS that's taking over. MediaWiki typically avoids using that designation. http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/CSS#.21important

Comment: Have you tried configuring position top/bottom in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules ?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a straightforward method to loading your CSS *after* the MediaWiki styles, as it is loaded by the primary resource loader via `load.php` on your page (**View source** on your web page to see your resource names listed first, generally, e.g. `ext.MySkin.styles` as outlined below), but I have found a solution which worked for me.

Within your `skin.json` or `extension.json` (or your PHP code) you can add a `"group"` field with the value of `"site"` to load your extension stylesheet after the main CSS for the site has been loaded.

For example, in your `skin.json` or `extension.json`:

```
{
    "name": "MySkin",
    ...
    "ResourceModules": {
        "ext.MySkin.styles": {
            "styles": [
                "my-skin.css"
            ],
            "group": "site"
        },
        "ext.MySkin.js": {
            "scripts": [
                "my-skin.js"
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Check out the documentation for [`$wgResourceModules`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgResourceModules#Details) as well as the [Group definitions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader/Features#Groups) which is linked there as well.

**MediaWiki** will load your extension/skin styles as a 2nd page request which is **not** optimized, but it will work in this application as you desire and your CSS will overwrite previous values within the skin, so for most applications this is appropriate, and works.